# How to create a warp route based on the path suffix?

Tags: rust, routes, rust-tokio, hyper, rust-warp

I need to create a route in `warp` for all URLs ending with an extension, regardless of the number of segments in the URL path, e.g. `path.ext`, `some/path.ext` and `some/other/path.ext` should be processed by the same route.

The closer I could get to a solution is [this technique](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues/19) but it requires that the path segments are fixed and known at compile time, which is not my case.

Comment: hyper doesn't provide this level of feature, you need to code it yourself or use a higher level framework

Comment: @Stargateur I'm using warp, which is a higher level framework based on hyper. I know I need to code the solution myself, I just need guidance on how.

Comment: warp name is confusing

Answer (score 0):

I decided to settle with a simple workaround. Posting here so maybe it can help someone.

In order to capture all URL paths ending with `.ext` in one route, while capturing all other paths not ending with `.ext` in another route, I wrote this:

```
let extension_path = warp::get().and_then(handle_extension);
let regular_path = warp::get().and_then(handle_regular);

let routes = extension_path.or(regular_path);
```

Then, in the `handle_extension` handler I issue a `warp::Rejection` if the path does not contains the `.ext` suffix, which will send the request to be processed by the next handler `handle_regular`.

This is a core paradigm in `warp`, you use rejections to perform control flow inside the routing filter chains.

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues/808) describing this limitation.